# Is there anything wrong with this jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

Its suppose to take an account from db and generate it but it just simply doesn't do anything when I click the button.

It's really important and it doesn't work. Am I missing anything on what I need to put? If so let me know and will add it.

```
<?php
if ($generator == "") {
    $generatorquery = "SELECT * FROM `accounts`";
} else {
    $generatorquery = "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `id` = " . $generator;
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, $generatorquery) or die(mysqli_error($con));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                            <div class="panel panel-success">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <span class="panel-title">' . $row["name"] . ' Generator</span>
                                    <div class="widget-menu pull-right">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <script>

                        $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("#' . $row['name'] . '").click(function(){
                         $("p[class=' . $row["name"] . ']").load("generate.php?account=' . $row["name"] . '&username=' . $username . '",function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
                            if(statusTxt=="error")
                            alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
                        });
                        });

                        $("#' . $row["name"] . '").click();
                        });
                        </script>
                        <p class="' . $row["name"] . '"></p>
                        <button type="button" id="' . $row["name"] . '" class="btn btn-success">Generate</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    ';
}
```

Comment: check your console. Plus, you're using `#` id's. remember that id's are unique. Use a class if that's the case. make sure you loaded the jQuery library also. Plus, no idea where `$generator` is defined. Check for errors (reporting).

Comment: @Fred-ii- Why did you remove the smiley, LoL.

Comment: @PraveenKumar it was too sad. The OP should have written something like... *"If you could help me out, that would be really cool `:-)`"* ;-) *"Think Joy"*.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever happens, `if (statusTxt=="error")` is never an error, but just one of the type of the output given by your PHP. It is a `success` function. So change your code to:

```
alert("Error: " + statusTxt.status + ": " + statusTxt.statusText);
```